# How do I dynamically allocate an array of objects in C++ with individual constructor parametes for each object?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector, constructor

Let's assume that I have a class

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo (const std::string&);
    virtual ~Foo()=default;
private:
    //some private properties
};
```

And I want to create many instances of this class. Since I aim for good performance, I want to allocate the memory at once for all of them (at this point, I know the exact number but only at runtime). However, each object shall be constructed with an individual constructor parameter from a vector of parameters

```
std::vector<std::string> parameters;
```

**Question:** How can this be achieved?

My first try was to start with a `std::vector<Foo>` and then `reserve(parameters.size())` and use `emplace_back(...)` in a loop. However I cannot use this approach because I use pointers to the individual objects and want to be sure that they are not moved to a different location in memory by the internal methods of `std::vector`. To avoid this I tried to delete the copy constructor of Foo to be sure at compile time that no methods can be called that might copy the objects to a different location but then I cannot use `emplace_back(...)` anymore. The reason is that in this method, the vector might want to grow and copy all the elements to the new location, it does not know that I reserved enough space.

Comment: If you reserve enough space, iterators (and pointers) should not be invalidated.

Comment: "it does not know that I reserved enough space." -- of course it does. There'd be no point in `reserve`'ing otherwise.

Comment: Research placement new

Comment: @RichardCritten - Why? That's what `std::vector` is for.

Comment: @Quentin I meant that it won't compile anymore because the compiler does not now that I won't call `emplace_back` more often than the reserved number.

Comment: @StoryTeller OP says he can't use `emplace_back`

Comment: Of course I can just leave the copy constructor and always try to avoid method calls that might invoke a movement of the objects to a new address but I think this is error prone and I wanted the compiler to do these checks.

Comment: @RichardCritten - OP *thinks* that. Doesn't mean it's a correct assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three possibilities:

- Use vector with `reserve` + `emplace_back`. You have the **guarantee** that your elements don't get moved as long as you don't exceed the capacity.
- Use malloc + placement new. This allows you to allocate raw memory and then construct each element one by one e.g. in a loop.
- If you already have a range of parameters from which to construct you objects as in the example, you can brobably (depending on your implementation of `std::vector`) use std::vector's iterator based constructor like this:
  `std::vector<Foo> v(parameters.begin(),parameters.end());`

First solution has the advantage to be much simpler and has all the other goodies of a vector like taking care of destruction, keeping the size around etc.
The second solution **might** be faster, because you don't need to do the housekeeping stuff of vector `emplace_back` and it works even with a deleted move / copy constructor if that is important to you, but it leaves you with dozens of possibilities for errors

The third solution - if applicable - is imho the best. It also works with deleted copy / move constructors, should not have any performance overhead and it gives you all the advantages of using a standard container.
It does however rely on the constructor first determining the size of the range (e.g. via `std::distance`) and I'm not sure if this is guaranteed for any kind of iterators (in practice, all implementations do this at least for random access iterators). Also in some cases, providing appropriate iterators requires writing some boilerplate code.

Comment: Since I guess that the second approach is often needed: Is there a STL container for this, something like a std::vector that does not automatically reserve new memory and instead just throws exceptions? Something like that would perfectly fit to my problem.

Comment: @phinz: No, unfortunately not. I added a third option which is probably the best in your case.

Comment: Does the third method need a copy constructor? If not, how does it know the number of elements it needs to reserve memory for? Counting in a first loop and constructing in a second?

Comment: The third option needs a constructor that accepts an argument that is of the specified parameter type (i.e. the type of an element of `parameters`).   That need not involve copy construction (unless `parameters` is a container of `Foo`, such as `std::vector<Foo>`, obviously)

Comment: @phinz: The third option might actually rely on a not-guaranteed property, that (at least for random access iterators), the implementation will first determine the size of the range and only then do allocation + construction. If you only have input iterators that obviously won't work